# CakePHP TranslateBehavior is driving me crazy

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I use CakePHP 1.3.2 with the integrated Translate Behavior.

The translations I save my several models in each table. Example:

```
class Page extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Page';
    var $actsAs = array(
        'Translate' => array('title', 'subtitle', 'menu')
    );
    var $translateModel = 'PageI18n';
...
}
```

Now after inserting of some data rows. Cake doesn't retrieve the i18n-data in the index-action anymore. The SQL-dump looks like this:

```
... WHERE I18n__title.locale = 'de_de' ...
```

But in the table "page_i18ns" the locale field is filled with '**deu**'

Why is Cake mixing the locale attribute? Where should I set the locale attribute? Somewhere in Model class?

In my AppController I set the language with `Configure::write('Config.language', $lang);` in the `beforeFilter()` function .... 'eng', 'deu', 'chi'

Comment: I know Cake and locale, but haven't used the Translate behavior. I just wanted to mention, that locale identifiers do look like en_en, de_de etc. and not like eng nor deu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following code in my ArticlesController:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Article->locale = $this->Session->read('Config.language');
}
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Oscar. In my case:
 $this->Article->locale = Configure::read('lang');

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed annoying CakePHP uses the locale instead of the language in the i18n table.
They might fix this bug, but chances are slim, because fixing this bug would break all existing i18n applications.

So i wrote a little helper function that translates a languageCode into a locale:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the "locale" from the language code (for i18n table)
 * Examples: en -> eng, en-us -> en_us, de -> deu, nl -> dut
 *
 * @param string $language
 * @return string
 */
function convertLanguageToLocale($language) {
    $i18n =& I18n::getInstance();
    $i18n->l10n->get($language);
    return $i18n->l10n->locale;
}
```